# Hide files/folders on my search but not in my side bar

Tags: search, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 and I want to exclude files/directories but not in my sidebar.

For example...

I have those files:

1. */doc/blabla/event.rb* with the text **some content** in it.
2. */app/event.rb* with the text **other content** in it.

So, with **Ctrl + P** (find files) and writing **"event**" I want to see only */app/event.rb*.

and, with **Ctrl + Shift + F** (find in all files) and writing **"content"** I want to see results, again, only for */app/event.rb*

I configure sublime with this values into my Preferences.sublime-settings:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["doc"],
```

this works beautifully but, it hides doc directory from sidebar too. I don't want this behavior. **I only want to hide files from my search**

Comment: This would be a fantastic feature to have in Sublime. Did you ever have any luck making this work?

Comment: Me too...I want this feature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For me, using Sublime 3 build 3083 `binary_file_patterns` was not working while I had the setting in the `project.sublime-project` file. Once I moved it to my Preferences.sublime-settings and added an '*' to the search it started excluding the folder from search results while leaving it in the sidebar. My Preferences.sublime-settings looks like so:

```
"binary_file_patterns":
    [
    "public/bower_components/*",
    "public/javascripts/vendor/*",
    "public-built/*"
    ],
```

and it works beautifully for me in sublime 3.

Also talked about in this post:
http://blog.lysender.com/2014/08/sublime-text-exclude-files-or-directories-from-go-to-anything-feature/

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and I can't figure out why. I've tried putting the full path to the directories in there. I've tried using the exact format you give above. For some reason, this doesn't work. I'm putting this in my sublime text 3 user preferences. I did copy over everything that was already in the default settings into user settings and then append to it. Any ideas?

Comment: @granmoe It didn't work properly for me until I made the paths /**/* to ensure everything was hidden, not just the first level of subdirectories. Give that a go.

Comment: @HarryFrancis Thanks, but I moved on to VS Code a few years ago and never looked back 

Answer (score 2):

You aren't looking for `folder_exclude_patterns`, rather `binary_file_patterns`. Check the default settings for the current values in case you woul dlike to keep the default values. I don't know if it works on folders, so you'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem. Recently I've been trowing every project that I'm not currently working to a `.old` folder and it became really annoying as the suggestions of Sublime are ordered it always in first place, so I did the same as @Typenine suggested and put it in `binary_file_patterns`. It is working great:

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["*/.old/*", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"]
```